# Edit PHP file using another PHP file and add a line on top of it

Tags: php, dynamic, line, fopen, updates

I have a PHP file that I want to dynamically add lines to it whenever I want.

Let's say I have foo.php which has these inside it:

```
<?php

echo "foo!";

?>
```

but I want to be able to add a line I specify in another file as a variable to be added on top of it and save the old content as well, to be like this:

```
<?php

echo "bar!";

echo "foo!";

?>
```

whenever I run my other file that adds the top line, I want it to add this line no matter what:

```
echo "bar!";
```

so if I run it twice the file would be like this:

```
<?php

echo "bar!";

echo "bar!";

echo "foo!";

?>
```

I know about the security issues and the file will be protected, I just don't know what's the best way to do this, fopen? curl? please help me find out the best way to do this. Thanks

Comment: file_get_contents() edit file_put_contents()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents('file')); 
array_splice($a, 1, 0, array('echo \'whatever\';'));
$a = implode("\r\n", $a);
file_put_contents('file', $a);
```

more simple:

```
$a="<?php\r\necho 'whatev';\r\n".substr($a,7);
```

Comment: I'm adding this comment anyway for less experienced PHP developers who've come to this answer/question: **modifying or _generating_ PHP scripts via scripting is _very dangerious_ only do this if you realy know what your doing and what the possible consequences can be**